# Animation organization of 4 robots

Tags: animation, armature, timeline

As you can see from the GIF image, each robot arm starts and ends in the same frame as the other robots. I would like the animations to start at different points, and, most importantly, for each armor, once its animation is finished, to restart immediately.

Using Blender's timeline, I have no idea how to achieve independent movement for each robot arm within the general animation.

[image]

Is it possible to loop each individual robot in an animation that lasts a total of one or two minutes?

Comment: Have you looked into the Nonlinear Animation window?

Comment: @moonboots I'm sorry to come across as a lazy person. Consider me a beginner. Your advice is valuable if it helps me go in the right direction, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the *Nonlinear Animation* window. First thing, switch the *Dope Sheet* to *Action Editor*, give a name to your action and click on the *Push Down* button:

[image]

The action disappears from the *Dope Sheet* but it's now available in the *Nonlinear Animation* window as a yellow strip. To repeat it, open the *N* panel and under *Strip > Action Clip* choose the number of repetition you want:

[image]

Select another armature, select the same action as the first one in the dropdown menu, and again push down into the *Nonlinear Animation* window (or select the second armature, shift select the first one and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> > *Link Animation Data*):

[image]

Again a yellow strip appears in the Nonlinear Animation window, offset it so that the animation begins earlier or later:

[image]

Comment: Thank you once again for your time. Your mini tutorial has guided me to discover some truly interesting things.

Comment: You're welcome    ;)   ......................